# UWP Get Outlook local contacts

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

After hours of research I achieved to get the contacts from Outlook using interop office library, using this code

```
        var outlookApplication = new Application();
        NameSpace mapiNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder contacts = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

        for (int i = 1; i < contacts.Items.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            var contact = (ContactItem)contacts.Items[i];
            Console.WriteLine(contact.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(contact.Email1Address);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

My goal is to do something like this in an UWP application. When I am trying to get the outlook interop library into an UWP I get an error. After some reading I found out that I can not use this COM library in an UWP application.
So my question is: How can I achieve to get outlook contacts in an UWP application, like in the above version?

Comment: Use Outlook Calendar REST Api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

Comment: I think that this API are only for Office 365, not for outlook on premise versions.

Comment: I have used it with Outlook Account and have not got any issue. I was working from JavaScript, but I don't think that it has any influence.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a web-based API like [Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contact), [Outlook Contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations) or Exchange Web Services.  UWP apps are sandboxed and cannot access email account data from Win32 email clients.  So you can only access web-based email data in Exchange, Office 365 or Outlook.com.

Comment: I also tried Exchange Web Services and It seems like I can't even add the package for EWS, in a UWP application.

Comment: You can't use the EWS Managed API, but you can use any REST-ful approach to sending EWS requests and processing the responses.

Comment: Let me make myself clear. I want to access an "on premise" Exchange Server and get from there, the Contacts. Can you elaborate your answer please? I tried EWS but it seems that it does not work in an UWP application.

Comment: Your are probably trying to use the EWS Managed API, which cannot be used in a UWP app. However all EWS methods can be called via REST by sending XML requests in POST or GET methods, and receiving XML responses. You don't need to set a reference to any Exchange APIs. See here for an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn789003.aspx